# Extract number from <a href="xxxxx=457822"> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

I am attempting to scape a web page and loop through two tables to 1) pull reference #, 2) Company name, 3) City, State. Here is my code and the results. Also, what is the best way to loop through all the tables on the page

Input:

```
<td><a href="TractorCo.cfm?CENSUS_NUM=587357">SALVAGE YARD</a> / ANYWHERE USA</td>
Output: SALVAGE YARD ANYWHERE, USA
```

Expected:    `587357 SALVAGE YARD ANYWHERE, USA`

```
link =""
for a in tbl[0].find_all('td'):
   str_cells = str(a)
   str_href = str_cells.strip('TractorCo.cfm?CENSUS_NUM=')
   cleantext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "lxml").get_text() #remove html jargon
   cleantext=' '.join(cleantext.split()) #remove excess spaces
   cleantext=cleantext.replace(" /", "")
   clean_list = []
   clean_list = cleantext
   print(clean_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to convert the td to a string and parse it again. Just use `a.find('a')` to get the anchor tag in the td.

The `strip()` method doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't remove a substring, it removes all the characters at the beginning or end of the string that are in the argument string.

```
for a in tbl[0].find_all('td'):
    link = a.find('a')
    if link and link.href.startswith('TractorCo.cfm?CENSUS_NUM='):
        num = link.href.split('=')[1]
        text = a.text.strip()
        print(num, text)
```

Comment: Ran code and received this Error msg: 'AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'href'.  Any thoughts on why 'href' not recognized as attribute?

Comment: I'm not sure why. `.find()` should just return a single element, not a result set. Did you change that to `a.find_all('a')`?

Comment: No, did not change to find_all. Printed link and it looks like this <a href="TractorCo.cfm?CENSUS_NUM=587357">SALVAGE YARD</a>Anywhere / USA>.

Comment: I don't know. Everything I can find about that message says that it happens when using the result of find_all when you need a single element.

Comment: Try `link[0].href`

Comment: Make changes as suggested and received  "KeyError:0". Added a print statement to see the content. Code submitted plus the error message. Also, note that the City and State are not showing.  line 22, in <module>
    if link and link[0].href.startswith('TractorCo.cfm?CENSUS_NUM='):
  File "C:\Users\pplfo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1519, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 0